# Talend frozen when click tMap component

Tags: java, talend

I have Talend integration Suite 4.2.4 installed on Mac OS 10.8.4 with java version 1.6.0_51.

I can open the project fine in Talend, but when I clicked any tMap component in the project, Talend froze, and I cannot do anything further.

I checked the .log file and it showed me these errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-08-06 13:27:48.765
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.ui.visualmap.table.DataMapTableView$37.focusGained(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3776)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1367)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1390)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1371)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.sendFocusEvent(Control.java:2940)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.sendFocusEvent(Canvas.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkFocus(Display.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeFirstResponder(Shell.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5086)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1130)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setWindowVisible(Shell.java:1740)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1173)
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.ui.MapperUI.createWindow(Unknown Source)
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.ui.MapperUI.createUI(Unknown Source)
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.managers.UIManager.createUI(Unknown Source)
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.MapperMain.createUI(Unknown Source)
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.MapperComponent.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.talend.designer.mapper.MapperComponent.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.talend.designer.core.ui.editor.nodes.NodePart.performRequest(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.gef.tools.SelectEditPartTracker.performOpen(SelectEditPartTracker.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.gef.tools.SelectEditPartTracker.handleDoubleClick(SelectEditPartTracker.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.mouseDoubleClick(AbstractTool.java:1069)
        at org.eclipse.gef.tools.SelectionTool.mouseDoubleClick(SelectionTool.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.gef.EditDomain.mouseDoubleClick(EditDomain.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.DomainEventDispatcher.dispatchMouseDoubleClicked(DomainEventDispatcher.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.draw2d.LightweightSystem$EventHandler.mouseDoubleClick(LightweightSystem.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3776)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1367)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1390)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1187)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3622)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3277)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

Answer (score 0):

We saw such issues of Talend hanging randomly at multiple points in TIS 4.x on Windows, when connected to SVN repository.  We recently moved to 5.2.x, which resolved most of such issues. Also try using Java Perspective instead of Integration.